# Templates and Javascript

Tags: javascript, go

So, I'm trying to implement CanvasJS into my project. I'm having a hard time trying to get the values from my structs to work in the  tags. It works fine for the HTML code, but I'm not sure how to get it work for the javascript. Is it a different syntax?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>results</title>
            <script src="http://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function () {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            title:{
                text: "My First Chart in CanvasJS"              
            },
            data: [              
            {
                // Change type to "doughnut", "line", "splineArea", etc.
                type: "column",
                /*dataPoints: [
                    { label: "Time",  y: 10  },
                    { label: "orange", y: 15  },
                    { label: "banana", y: 25  },
                    { label: "mango",  y: 30  },
                    { label: "grape",  y: 28  }
                ]*/
                dataPoints: [
                    {{range .Pair}}
                        {label: {{.Time}}, y: {{.Value}}}
                    {{end}}
                ]
            }
            ]
        });
        chart.render();
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{.Id}}</h1>
    <ol>
    {{range .Pair}}
        <ul>
            <li>Time: {{.Time}}</li>
            <li>Value: {{.Value}}</li>
        </ul>
        {{end}}
    </ol>

    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: You need commas between the properties.

Comment: I'm with @Pointy on this: the line which constructs your "label: " entries is missing the delimiting comma at its end.  Few more points in no particular oder: 1) some older IE versions might fail on the comma after the final array element; 2) since the object you pass to the Chart ctor is JSON, you might reconsider your approach: serialize this stuff to a JSON string outside your template and then embed that string; 3) next time please take your time and provide an MCVE on http://play.golang.org -- it's your problem so please help us to help you.

Comment: You need to use something like https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js or https://github.com/carlcraig/tc-angular-chartjs